# Apple iOS Enterprise Developer Program Device Check

Tags: html, ios, download, user-agent

I'm working on an application with the iOS developer program.  I understand that I need to link the download button on my website to a manifest .plist file, which gives the location of the app.  I also understand that this file must be downloaded by an iOS device.  So, how can I ensure that the manifest file is only downloaded by an iOS device?

Comment: So is this a Web programming question or a device programming question? It's hard to tell.

Comment: Web programming, but I'd assume apple developers could answer my question well

Comment: Then why would you  tag it as Objective-C if you have no objective-c code? Have you looked into User-Agent strings and hiding a div if the user agent isn't one for iOS?

Comment: No, I am an iOS developer and I have limited knowledge of user agents.  Could you point me to some information?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Agent If you are using PHP or even JavaScript, it is trivial to hide a DIV based on the request's user-agent string.

Comment: Could I instead block the download from commencing after the user clicks on the download button, if their user-agent does not match?

Comment: Yes, that would work. If you would like, I can make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check to see if the environment `HTTP_USER_AGENT` contains the string `iPhone` or `iPad` (because even the iPod touch has iPhone in the user-agent-string).

```
<?php
   $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

   if ((stripos(user_agent, "iPhone") == FALSE) && (stripos(user_agent, "iPad") == FALSE))
        // do something here (e.g. hide the div, prevent file download, etc.
?>
```